# Simple program using transform and lambdas isn't working

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting these errors. Why?

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63:0,
>                    from prog.cpp:2:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _OIter = std::back_insert_iterator >; _UnaryOperation = main()::]’:
>   prog.cpp:10:98:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4951:2: error: no match for call to ‘(main()::) (int&)’
>   prog.cpp:10:64: note: candidates are:
>   In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63:0,
>                    from prog.cpp:2:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4951:2: note: int (*)(int, int) 
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4951:2: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
>   prog.cpp:10:79: note: main()::
>   prog.cpp:10:79: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    std::vector<int> r;

    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(r), [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; });
}
```

This code is supposed to add up each pair of numbers and put it into the `r` vector but it's not working. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've picked the overload of [`transform()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) that works on a single range - and thus expects a *unary* functor to be provided as the last argument.

If what you want is to work on *two* ranges (perhaps two "copies" of the same range?), then you should do:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), 
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^
    std::back_inserter(r), [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; });
```

So here is the full code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    std::vector<int> r;

    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(),
        std::back_inserter(r), [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; });
}
```

And here is a compiling [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=649ca11e1e51d8d29dd8b92ba81efdff-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

However, unless you just wanted to practice with the overload of `std::transform()` that operates on two input ranges, you could follow [Konrad Rudolph's advice from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001029/simple-program-using-transform-and-lambdas-isnt-working/17001052#comment24564475_17001052), and write:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(r), [] (int a) { return a * 2; });
```

If, instead, you want to perform a sum of each pair of consecutive elements and store the result in the `r` vector while using a transform-like approach, then you may resort to Boost.Range, and write something like:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

// ...

namespace rng = boost::adaptors;

// This will fill r with values { 3, 7, 11 }
boost::transform(
    v | rng::strided(2),
    std::make_pair(v.begin() + 1, v.end()) | rng::strided(2),
    std::back_inserter(r),
    [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; });
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=77a02f98b9f0150fc19943a039b723fd-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

Also, [as pointed out by NeelBasu in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001029/simple-program-using-transform-and-lambdas-isnt-working/17001052?noredirect=1#comment24566078_17001052), instead of using `std::make_pair()` to define the second range, you could write a more expressive (and compact) version based on the `sliced` range adaptor:

```
boost::transform(
    v | rng::strided(2),
    v | rng::sliced(1, v.size()) | rng::strided(2),
    std::back_inserter(r),
    [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; });
```

Comment: Not sure if that’s what OP actually wants since that would be equivalent to the unary version with the lambda `[](int a){return 2*a;}` “each pair of numbers” sounds more like OP wants to enumerate all pairwise numbers (which wouldn’t really be a job for `transform`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: After re-reading the answer, I think you're right. Will edit again

Comment: No, what you have is fine. Thank you.

Comment: @MemyselfandI: Well, but what I am showing does not add up each consecutive pairs of elements. Is that what you want to do? Perhaps you may consider using Boost.Range in that case

Comment: @MemyselfandI: I added an example using Boost.Range that does what I think you were trying to do with `transform()` (but uses `boost::transform()` instead of `std::transform()`)

Comment: No Cubbi what I wanted you did well with in your first example. I don't even know what's happening in the second one anyway...

Comment: @MemyselfandI so you should edit your question, because what you are asking is something entirely different.

Comment: @MemyselfandI: The last example does what your question seems to ask for (take pairs of consecutive elements in the array, compute their sum, and store the result). Like, `1 + 2 = 3`; store `3`. `3 + 4 = 7`; store `7`; `5 + 6 = 11`; store `11`.

Comment: can't this be just `boost::transform(v | strided(2), v | sliced(1, v.size()) | strided(2),
            std::back_inserter(r), [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; });` why need pairs ?

Comment: @NeelBasu: Absolutely, that's also a valid alternative. Perhaps even better than mine. I'll add it to the answer, thank you!